# Skype API Fetching Host information

Tags: ip, host, skype

I am developing an application in c# that requires the hostname or IP address of a specific Skype user, so that my server infrastructure can establish itself appropriately to the specific customer that one of my employees will be speaking to, over their Skype messaging sessions.

I have done some research over the internet to find these "Skype resolver" services, that can be used for malicious purposes, I assure you that this is not my intention, however, due to the fact that I do not support malicious activity, I would rather build my own method of fetching an IP address by utilising a Skype username, rather than support these malicious organization by using their tools.

So what do I need to do, in order to get these IP addresses from Skype usernames?